# CSS Message ul li span overflowing on x not y

Tags: html, css

I've got an issue with my chat window, every long message overflows onto the x, and I'm trying to force it to over flow onto the height / y axis, I've tried adding overflow-x:none; and height:auto;, but doesnt seem to work.
This is what it looks like:http://www.socialnetwk.com/chatbug.png

Here is my code:

```html
<style>

.chat-box {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: none;
}
.header {
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #6d84b4;
}
.messages {
    height: 80%;
    overflow-x: none;
    background-color: green;
    background-color: rgb(237, 239, 244);
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.messages ul {
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow-x: none;
}
.messages ul li {
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    clear: both;
    overflow-x: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.messages ul li span {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    height:auto;
    overflow-x: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: grey;
}
.messages ul li span.received {
    float: left;
}
.messages ul li span.received:after {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -8.5px;
    top: 7px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid white;
}
.messages ul li span.received:before {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -9px;
    top: 7px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid black;
}
.messages ul li span.sent:after {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -8px;
    top: 6px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid #dbedfe;
}
.messages ul li span.sent:before {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -9px;
    top: 6px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid black;
}
.messages ul li span.sent {
    float: right;
    background-color: #dbedfe;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.input-box {
    background-color: white;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.input-box textarea {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 278px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    resize: none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
}
.MsgInputHidden {
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
}

</style>

<div class="chat-box">
    <div id="messages" class="messages message-window" friend_id="<?=$FriendName->id ?>">
        <ul class="message">
            <li> 
                <span class="sender">LongTextGoesInThisBoxLongTextGoesInThisBoxLongTextGoesInThisBox</span>

            <li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the corresponding markup / HTML?

Comment: Please share a working example here with HTML and CSS altogether. It will help understanding of your problem easily.

Comment: Your closing `li` tag is malformed. Probably not an issue here, but worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS property

```
.messages ul li span {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<style>
  .chat-box {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: none;
  }
  .header {
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #6d84b4;
  }
  .messages {
    height: 80%;
    overflow-x: none;
    background-color: green;
    background-color: rgb(237, 239, 244);
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  .messages ul {
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow-x: none;
  }
  .messages ul li {
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    clear: both;
    overflow-x: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
  .messages ul li span {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    height: auto;
    overflow-x: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: grey;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
  .messages ul li span.received {
    float: left;
  }
  .messages ul li span.received:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -8.5px;
    top: 7px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid white;
  }
  .messages ul li span.received:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -9px;
    top: 7px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid black;
  }
  .messages ul li span.sent:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -8px;
    top: 6px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid #dbedfe;
  }
  .messages ul li span.sent:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -9px;
    top: 6px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid black;
  }
  .messages ul li span.sent {
    float: right;
    background-color: #dbedfe;
  }
  .clear {
    clear: both;
  }
  .input-box {
    background-color: white;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .input-box textarea {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 278px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    resize: none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
  }
  .MsgInputHidden {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="chat-box">
    <div id="messages" class="messages message-window" friend_id="<?=$FriendName->id ?>">
      <ul class="message">
        <li>
          <span class="sender">LongTextGoesInThisBoxLongTextGoesInThisBoxLongTextGoesInThisBox</span>

          <li>


      </ul>
    </div>
```